# How to properly store file lines in a char array? (C++)

Tags: c++, string, input, char

I'm trying to read each line of a .txt file into a char array.

```
for(int i = 0; i <10; i++)
  { 
       fin.getline(lineChar, 164);      // place txt line into char array
       for(int a = 9; a<164; a+=1)      // remove first nine chars of garbage
           lineChar[a-9] = lineChar[a];
       name = getPlaceName(lineChar);
       cout<< name<<endl;
  }
```

I know exactly the length of each line (164) as I've checked and tested it so that I crash if I try to get 165 characters. This works for the first line, but then I get gibberish afterwards.

```
Aaron
g



5 
9
```

The text file has lines such as:

```
  PA4200100Aaronsburg                                                            485      209       1349064             0    0.520877    0.000000 40.900946 -77.453383
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Store each char of txt file into array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12900823/store-each-char-of-txt-file-into-array)

Comment: Change the constant `164` to `165` in both places so that you copy down the trailing null.

Comment: Why aren't you using std::string?

Comment: @ejp I tried that and it caused a crash

Answer (score 1):

You can use std for read the file.

```
std::string str;

std::vector<std::string> myvec;

while( std::getline( myfile, str ) )
{
    myvec.push_back( str );
}
```

If you need take the next 70 chars after the first nines (the name), you can use:

```
std:cout << str.substr( 9, 70 );
```